# Problem with Samba shared folder

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive, ethernet, mount, file-sharing

I have a USB HDD formatted in NTFS connected to my router, all my PC(Windows,Os X,Linux) can use it, also Raspberry works on it using the file manager.This is the situation

[image]

I try to mount the folder torrent by raspberry's terminal using

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g //192.168.0.1/torrent /home/NAS -o username=***,password=***,workgroup=WORKGROUP,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=pi,gid=pi,forceuid,forcegid 0 0`

but its outcome is

[image]

I try also with cifs instead of ntsf

`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/torrent /home/NAS -o username=***,password=***,workgroup=WORKGROUP,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=pi,gid=pi,forceuid,forcegid 0 0`

But also this time it fails, the result is

[image]

I am not able to find the mistake. Someone can help me?

Comment: Is the pi running Raspbian? That may be part of your problem.

Comment: Yes! Raspbian is my os, since I'm new on raspberry and reading some forums, they said that Raspbian is the most user friendly OS. I need to use the Raspberry as cloud server and media center. Which os you recommend me?

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem, in a forum I have found the hint of updating the firmware of pi using the command sudo rpi - update but also this doesn't work. I haven't more ideas! I'm waiting your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I have solved my problem with two steps:

1. updating my pi's firmware by

   ```
   sudo rpi-update
   sudo reboot
   ```
2. putting **sec=ntlm** in the options of call to mount

So the final command that I use is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/torrent /home/NAS -o uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,username="YOURUSERNAME",password="YOURPASSWORD",sec=ntlm
```

To use the /etc/fstab to mount automatically at every reboot the correct line is

```
//192.168.0.1/torrent /home/NAS cifs iocharset=utf8,username= YOURUSERNAME,password= YOURPASSWORD,sec=ntlm 0 0
```